# Android Webview shows nothing occasionally

Tags: android, oauth, webview

I have a webview that loads google oAuth page. That requires multiple redirections before arriving on the final page that asks user to grant access.

Occassionally, the webview doesn't show any data on the screen at all. What I notice is that it almost always show the page when I am debugging (breakpoints). Pressumably, this is a timing issue.

So to get it all of the way, I have done this:
1) shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is overriden so that i can redirect on the same webview.
2) OnReceivedError and most of the methods on WebViewClient and WebChromeClient are overriden and logged.
3) I added a picture listener to the webview to make sure when any picture is loaded, i am invlidating mywebview

From research, I know that the sequence of URLs being loaded are the same for both the case of working and the case of not working.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I know this is quite an old question, but for others who stumble onto this problem, check if returning false from the overridden shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method in your WebViewClient solves it.